# Is there a way to handle Allow option in "Access your location in JavaScript" in iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I would like to handle Allow option in "Access your location in JavaScript" in iOS,is there a way to do it.Kindly help me with a snippet.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you request the location of the device, the decision on how to display the Allow/Deny alert is only up to the browser.

Different browsers have different behaviors, but **you can't** override or bypass them. That would be a security flaw.